# Remote login with pre-boot authentication (KVM switch)

Tags: remote, disk-encryption, kvm-switch

I want to use full disk encryption with pre-boot authentication (Truecrypt) and somehow remotely enter the pre-boot password. KVM switch is apparently what I need.

There seem to be billion different types of KVM switches, so which kind should I get?

I have an ADSL modem connected to a router running OpenWRT (router has a USB port, haven't really used it so I don't know if it's any good) connected to a desktop computer.

Considerations:

- It'd be nice if I could plug in a laptop to the KVM and use my desktop mouse and keyboard to control my laptop and get the laptop's video output on my desktop monitor.
- I might purchase another monitor to go along with my current one, so dual monitor usage would be a plus (referring to the previous point)
- No super expensive, enterprise grade solutions (I'm a student and a home user)

I'd appreciate if anyone using a KVM switch for similar purposes would share the details of their setup.

Also if there are other things you think I should consider when buying a KVM switch, please share.

Is printer and other USB device sharing possible with a KVM?

Answer (score 0):

You can find KVMs to share printers and USB devices but I wouldn't bother.

I suggest you share the Printer and USB devices using a ehternet cable and gigabit ethernet.

As for the KVM for the laptop, the easiest solution is to see if your BIOS will accept two keyboards.  Most BIOS these days will.  just plug a USB keyboard into any KVM and plug the USB cord to the USB port on the laptop.

Few KVMs these days seem to have four USB ports.  Couldn't find any atm, but I'm sure they are out there.  But you know what you need.  Four USB outs, Two VGA outs.

Usually with these "I need to buy X" it help immensely to know which country you are in.  Some places don't ship outside the continental US.  And this site seems to be teeming with foreigners. . .

(Darting eyes)  (Darting eyes)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not in the US (European), but you could definitely suggest products from US-only stores. I could search for those products inside the EU or use a remailing service (expensive but gets the job done).